# CruiseControl.net and cronTrigger

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

So, I'm having this odd issue with my CruiseControl.net project. I have a ccnet.config file that goes and pulls from my bitbucket repo, runs a basic build, then runs some unit tests, and then finally copies the tested files out to the webroot. Seems pretty basic, even for being my first time using CC.Net.

I, of course, would like this to run when I do commits. Failing writing some sort of web page that bitbucket can invoke through it's services framework, I settled for having CC run a scheduled build, and only run the full build if there's source control changes.

After some googling, I found out that in 1.6, it has a cronTrigger. Excactly what I need. So, I add the following chunk to my config:

```
<cronTrigger>        
  <cronExpression>*/5 * * * *</cronExpression>
</cronTrigger>
```

Then it triggers fine, but then I get a loop of this in the console:

```
[HMS:INFO] Calling hg log -r tip --template {rev} --noninteractive
[HMS:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] in working directory [C:\build\hms\src] with arguments [log -r tip --template {rev} --noninteractive]
[HMS:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on [C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] to default Normal
[8:DEBUG] [HMS C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] standard-error stream closed -- null received in event
[7:DEBUG] [HMS C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] 60
[7:DEBUG] [HMS C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] standard-output streamclosed -- null received in event
[3:DEBUG] [HMS C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\hg.exe] process exited event received
[HMS:INFO] No modifications detected.
```

This loop continues until I go in and remove the `cronTrigger` block. I don't really want this thing busy-waiting on my server for a change, and I'm sure BitBucket doesn't smile upon several requests per second.

So, in short, how do I stop this thing from molesting bitbucket? Stop using CC.Net? Resign myself to hitting the "Build" button?

Also: my ccnet.config file for reference: http://pastebin.com/6jSPxVTk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I said screw it, I moved to Hudson instead. A bit heavier on my server, but it supports a URL to post to, so I can drop that into BitBucket's "Services" option, so no polling.

I also get a free Jabber bot, and Chuck Norris.